# Passing value of register to macro

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm developing an assembly program for school and I'm running into a "problem".

My teacher gave me an already-coded macro `WAIT` (that I **cannot** modify) which has this body :

```
.macro WAIT delay
     LDR r0, =\delay
     @ code
.endm
```

So I do understand that I have a to pass a **value** (i.e. `0xCAFE`).

Since I don't like code-redundancy, I would like to call this macro in a function which takes the register `r1` as the delay to pass to the `WAIT` macro.

Is there any way I can do something like : `WAIT value(r1)` ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: No, because the `LDR` instruction loads a register from something other than another register. However you can write a new macro that can do what you are looking for.

Comment: @FrankC. Yes I think I'll end up doing that...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a ARM like processor, and that code / literals are not placed in read only memory, it may be possible to get clever and use an instance of the WAIT macro that forces the usage of a literal:

```
        LDR     R0, =\delay
```

such as delay == 0x55555555 , to generate a constant in memory so that the instruction is

```
        LDR     R0,[PC + offset]
```

For example, assuming that this is the only instance where a literal is used for LDR RX,=literal, then this could work:

```
        ;       ...
        LEA     R2,delay0
        STR     R1,[R2]
        WAIT    =0x55555555      ;force a literal at delay0
        ;       ...
delay0                           ;address of literal 0x55555555
        LTORG
```

As commented in the original question, it would be better to create a new macro. It's also possible that the macro inline implementation causes it to be very precise.

Comment: This could be a solution indeed! But I think my teacher would prefer some redundant lines instead of doing calculations :) Anyway, I'll keep this idea in mind for other projects. Thanks!